# How to read text from a website, knowing the ID

Tags: javascript

If this can only be done with PHP, then say so, otherwise, I would want a solution in vanilla Javascript.
How can I get the text within a tag (say, `h1`) from another website, when I know the id of the tag?
And if possible, is there a way to get text after the first instance of another word (say, "asdf") somewhere else?

Comment: To be clear, you're trying to read data from a website that does NOT run your JS code? The topic here would be "web scraping".

Comment: You can't read other web sites with browser JavaScript, unless the other site specifically allows it (and >99.9% don't allow it.)

Comment: Definitive look at all the options and how they are not useful: http://scraping.pro/web-scraping-with-javascript-load-html-page/

Comment: Well, thanks for the replies. By vanilla JS I meant browser-based non-jQuery JS, but I don't really know my terms.